# Hoc React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am trying to use an HOC component in React with a functional component, but when using hooks I keep getting the error `React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback.` What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

```
const HOC = (WrappedComponenet, entity) => {
  return function () {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [term, setTerm] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${entity}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data));
    }, []);

    let filteredData = data.slice(0, 10).filter((d) => {
      if (entity === "users") {
        const { name } = d;
        return name.indexOf(term) >= 0;
      }
      if (entity === "todos") {
        const { title } = d;
        return title.indexOf(term) >= 0;
      }
    });

    return <WrappedComponenet data={filteredData} />;
  };
};
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please add `entity` in useEffect dependency.

Comment: I believe functional component expects us to return Elements rather then an unnamed function, if you wan to you should use a Named function and then render it by returning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```
const HOC = (WrappedComponenet, entity) => {
  function MyCustomComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [term, setTerm] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${entity}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data));
    }, []);

    let filteredData = data.slice(0, 10).filter((d) => {
      if (entity === "users") {
        const { name } = d;
        return name.indexOf(term) >= 0;
      }
      if (entity === "todos") {
        const { title } = d;
        return title.indexOf(term) >= 0;
      }
    });

    return <WrappedComponenet data={filteredData} />;
  };

  return <MyCustomComponent/>
};
```